# Can mathematical data from a recorded video be extracted to a computer file?

Tags: video, video-recording

Can mathematical data (for example, stop watch/timer values) from a smartphone recorded video be extracted to a computer file for plotting graphs ??

*I have recorded a video of an on-screen measurements which are changing very fast (of the order of milliseconds). I need to get those values in output of any format (say MS word file) and plot them in any software (say MS office).

Comment: How is the data stored / presented ?

Comment: I have recorded a video of an on-screen measurements which are changing very fast (of the order of milliseconds). I need to get those values in output of any format (say MS word file) and plot them in any software (say MS office)

Comment: Smartphone shoots at average frame rate of 30 fps. You require two orders of magnitude more precise data. It simply is not there. But otherwise, you can use tools like those that are used to capture burned-in subtitles, if the numbers appear in the same location on the screen. Instead of doing OCR on video frames how about outputting the data into a file?